# Best Way to Bind an ES6 Class Method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES5 one would create a bound method like so:

```
function FakeClass() {
    this.foo = this._foo.bind(this);
    // or, with Underscore/Lodash
    // this.foo = _.bind(this.foo, this);
    // or
    // _.bindAll(this, 'foo');
}
FakeClass.prototype._foo = function() { ...
```

With ES6 syntax this doesn't seem to go away; it seems like I still have to explcitily bind the method:

```
class FakeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = this._foo.bind(this);
    }
    _foo() { ...
}
```

So, my question is: there a better way that's actually part of (current or planned) JS?

**NOTE:**  I've seen some Stack Overflow answers mention this syntax:

```
class FakeClass {
    foo = () => { ...
}
```

However when I try that syntax only Babel allows it; Chrome and my IDE both tell me that's invalid syntax.  Presumably this is because the `foo = () => {` syntax comes from some unfinished ES7 or ES8 proposal.  However, I haven't been able to Google an answer, and until I do I'm hesitant to add (potentially invalid in the future) syntax to my code.

Comment: While it's not exactly the same title question, I think the duplicate answers all your questions.

Comment: It confirms that the `=>` syntax is not something I want to use, and that (unfortunately) I'm stuck with the `this.foo = this._foo.bind(this)` pattern.  Thanks.