# Call a member method of an instantiated class in a callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this class:

```
class A {
  name = 'foo';

  displayName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

And I'd like to call the `displayName` method within a callback after the instantiation. I've done this:

```
const a = new A();
someCode('blabla', a.displayName.bind(a));
```

But I don't like this. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the `bind` as not being elegant?

Comment: The class syntax you are using is not valid ES6. But if you are using experimental syntax anyway, you might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35495919/1048572)

Comment: `const A = new A();` will always throw an exception. I assume you meant `const a = new A();`?

Comment: @nils the `bind(a)`

Comment: @Bergi Yes I edited.

Comment: @Bergi I already read this answer but didn't find something that suits my needs...

Comment: @Kerumen the question Bergi is linking to answers you question precisely.

Comment: @nils It's all about binding `this`. Nevermind I guess this is the only way to do this.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your point then. Is it not about binding this?

Comment: It is. But not _inside_ the class.

Comment: @Kerumen If you don't want to bind it inside the class (which would make the callback passing most elegant: `someCode('blabla', a.displayName)`) in any way, you have to [bind it outside](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572). If you don't like `bind`, function expressions or arrow functions are basically your only alternative.

Comment: @Bergi How can I bind it inside the class? I'm interested!

Comment: @Kerumen Or maybe if you're into [experimental syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31221199/1048572), you might use `someCode('blabla', ::a.displayName)`. But really you have to tell us *what* you don't like about `someCode('blabla', a.displayName.bind(a));` to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Kerumen Oops, I thought I used that link as the dupe target already. If you want to bind inside the class, your question is essentially an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35495919/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Ok I ended up using the (experimental) arrow function syntax so I don't have to bind it in the callback. Thanks!

Comment: It's not the arrow functions that are experimental, it's the assignment statement outside of the constructor (like you did with `name = 'foo'`)